# Why did the specific charge of an electron show that the electron is smaller than an atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, electrons

Why is the JJ Thomson experiment for specific charge seen as such strong evidence for the electron being smaller than the hydrogen ion? He showed that the specific charge of an electron was over 1000x greater than a hydrogen ion. This means that the electron is either much lighter(as known today), or more charged. Since the idea that atoms were indivisible was so ingrained at the time, what evidence made it clear to rule out the latter? As only this leads to the conclusion that it is smaller than the atom.

Comment: Because atoms are neutral.

Comment: @JonCuster My bad; hydrogen ion.

Comment: The point is that one electron and one hydrogen ion together make one neutral atom. That fixes the charges to be opposite in sign and equal in magnitude. (Now just why that occurs is a different question.)

Comment: @JonCuster I think this evidence is circular because it wasn't known at the time, although these things are obvious now. The answer seems to be that they didnt know for sure, but it was just a reasonable assumption and no one was really arguing otherwise, and it was not until Millikan oil drop that it was known.

Comment: Given currents on anode and cathode, it is quite clear that one electron is not part of 1000 hydrogen ions.